# How to send an email in Django based on a condition?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've a model where users fill out the form and enter details like start date and end date, based on the start date I want the emails to be sent automatically. Like start date is 03/23/21 and I want a email to be sent after 10 days and then again after 20 days. Currently I'm using Amazon SES for email service.
Can someone please guide me how to set this up?
I checked CRON and CELERY but couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Check out https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#basics in celery

Comment: I think celery should be good for periodical checks in DB for suitable records. Do you need to setup your Django app with Amazon SES?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I've stored the date in models. I only needed help in setting up celery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a table to save start date.

Use task(windows) or cron(linux) to execute a django-admin command to send a email.

How to write a custom django-admin command

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Using AWS SES to send a email:

https://github.com/django-ses/django-ses

You should set aws ses first.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-set-up.html